Flask Application Throws Error When List in Form
I have something like "data" or "data[0]" is undefined when I submit a form in my flask application.
This flask application connects to a MS Access DB. I have something like:
@app.route('/data_page/<policy_number>')
def data_page(policy_number):
    # sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Owner.Policy, Owner, tbl_Owner.Address1, tbl_Owner.Address2 FROM tbl_Owner INNER JOIN [tbl_Transactions(OnMonthliversary)] ON tbl_Owner.Policy = [tbl_Transactions(OnMOnthliversary)].Policy WHERE tbl_Owner.Policy = '" + str(policy_number) + "'"
    sql = "SELECT Policy, Owner, Address1, Address2 FROM tbl_Owner WHERE Policy = '" + str(policy_number) + "'"
    policy_info_query = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
    sql = "SELECT Date, Premium FROM [tbl_Transactions(OffMonthliversary)] WHERE Policy = '" + str(policy_number) + "'"
    policy_transactions_off_monthliversary_query = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
    sql = "SELECT Date, Forced_BAV FROM [tbl_Transactions(OnMonthliversary)] WHERE Policy = '" + str(policy_number) + "'"
    policy_transactions_on_monthliversary_query = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
    data = [policy_info_query, policy_transactions_off_monthliversary_query, policy_transactions_on_monthliversary_query]
    
    return flask.render_template('Policy Data.jinja', data = data)

Here data is a list of lists. So in my JINJA template I have something like:
/* MORE HTML ABOVE */

   {{ components.navigation_bar() }}
    <body>
        <main>
            <section class = "grid_widget">
                <div class = "display_wrapper" id = "display_policy_info">
                    <form class = "display" method = "post" action = " {{ url_for('data_page_handler') }}" id = "display_policy_info_form">
                        <div class = "display_title">
                            <h1> {{ data[0][0][0] }} </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "display_data">
                            <p> OWNER: </p> <textarea name = "owner_name" id = "display_owner" disabled> {{ data[0][0][1] }} </textarea>
                            <br>
                            <p> ADDRESS: </p>
                            <input class = "display_address" name = "owner_address_part_one" value = "{{ data[0][0][2] }}" disabled>
                            <br>
                            <input class = "display_address" name = "owner_address_part_two" value = "{{ data[0][0][3] }}" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class = "display_widget">
                        <div class = "display_continuation"> <h1> &zwnj; </h1> </div>
                        <i class = "fa fa-pencil-square-o edit_display_screen" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

/* MORE HTML BELOW */

When I load this everything appears perfect. However, the problem is when I submit my form, all the lists throws an error. It says like data[0][0][0] doesn't exist. That's not even part of the input! That's in the <h1></h1> tag! I don't understand!
P.S. The action was originally url_for('data_page', policy_number = 'data[0][0][0]') but then I recently created another endpoint and changed it to data_page_handler where it is NOT a dynamic URL route. That handler looks like:
@app.route("/data_page", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def data_page_handler():
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        test = flask.request.form
        print(test)
    return flask.render_template('Policy Data.jinja')

Please advise. I searched everywhere on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything.

Don't use concatenation to substitute variables into SQL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

If the query doesn't return any rows, data[0] will be an empty list. This will happen if the policy number is invalid.
